# Alternatively replace chars in the string with the corresponding index

Tags: python, string, list-comprehension

How to replace the alternative characters in the string with the corresponding index without iterating? For example:

```
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

should be returned as:

```
'a1c3e5g7i9k11m13o15q17s19u21w23y25'
```

I have the below code to achieve this. *But is there a way to skip the loop or, more pythonic way to achieve this*:

```
string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
new_string = ''
for i, c in enumerate(string):
    if i % 2:
        new_string += str(i)
    else:
        new_string += c
```

where `new_string` hold my required value

Comment: "Without iterating" and "pythonic way" ... what if the most pythonic way is with iterating?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), and re-join the characters with [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join); the latter avoids repeated (slow) string concatenation):

```
newstring = ''.join([str(i) if i % 2 else l for i, l in enumerate(string)])
```

Note that you can't evade iteration here. Even if you defined a large list of pre-stringified odd numbers here (`odds = [str(i) for i in range(1, 1000, 2)]`) then re-use that to use slice assignment on a list `string_list[1::2] = odds[:len(string) // 2]` Python has to iterate under the hood to re-assign the indices. That's the nature of working with an arbitrary-length sequence.

Comment: User has mentioned that he wants to skip the `for` loop. *List comprehensions* are also the type of loop

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri No, they are not, no more than the `map` you used.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri: and `map()` loops too. You *have* to here, there is no way to avoid iteration *in some form or other*.

Comment: In case  if I was having `list` instead of `str`, still list comprehension was recommended or replacing via slicing?

Comment: @experimenting_python: It *could* be faster, but I find the list comprehension with `enumerate()` to be clearer, easier to read.